# Xcode is hidden in OS X 10.8.2

Tags: xcode, macos

Now I am using OS X 10.8.2. I have installed Xcode 4.5 on my Mac. It has completely installed and I am able to open sample Xcode projects. The problem is Xcode is not displayed in the Application folder.

How can I make Xcode visible in the Finder?

[image]

Comment: Can you open Terminal and run `ls -ld /Applications/X*` to see if it got installed there at all?

Comment: @patrix this command shows `drwxr-xr-x@ 3 andrew  admin  102 Aug  5  2012 /Applications/Xcode.app`

Comment: Looks like it is not installed properly or something like that so Finder sees Xcode.app as a directory. Try reinstalling

Comment: @Mark not at all... Xcode is working fine... There is no problem with the installation.

Comment: On Mac OS X all applications are folders. They appear to be single files through the magic of the Finder.

Comment: @MarkThalman - Yes however if installed correctly applications should not show as Folders in Finder and the menu the OP shows

Comment: @Mark I agree. There will probably be other issues which is why I recommended starting over if there is any weird behavior in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Xcode is working without a problem, it is probably installed correctly. You can unhide the application the same way you unhide the ~/Library folder on Lion and later. Open the terminal and enter the following command:

```
chflags nohidden /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Xcode should be visible in the Finder.

If you have any problems with Xcode not building or running properly I would recommend deleting Xcode and reinstalling from the App store.